# How to save a file in Vim in a way as if :wq had been issued but without exiting the editor?

Tags: undo-redo

I use [`gh` (the official GitHub CLI tool)](https://github.com/cli/cli) to edit my gists from the terminal. When I issue `gh gist edit <gist-ID>` then Vim opens, I do the deed, and  when I save the file and quit Vim (by using `:wq`), the gist will get updated.

My problem is that if I need to do subsequent edits, and use the same `gh` command above, it does open up the gist, but the undo buffer is empty (because it is another temporary file). It would be helpful to send a signal to the terminal that the file has been closed (I assume that is what triggers the push) but without exiting Vim. Is this possible?

EDIT: Just realized that even if this is possible, I have other trouble on my hand, because the subsequent closure of the file may not trigger anything and/or even deleted from `/tmp`. Anyway, still interested:)

Comment: I have created some vimscript to do gists from within vim itself: https://gist.github.com/habamax/2b99e5eb82500d88418bf9e640918dd3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you would like to trigger gist publish from within spawned from `gh gist edit <gist-ID>` vim without closing said vim.

There is no `gh gist push` or similar that you could use in `:!gh ...` command, but what you can try is to use regular `!git push` command -- each gist in github is a separate git repo.

Have a look at the vimscript as an inspiration: https://gist.github.com/habamax/2b99e5eb82500d88418bf9e640918dd3

There as I already pointed I use `gh` and `git` tools to edit and publish existing files as gists. The command I use in the end to publish a gist is:

```
call system("git add -A && git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m 'vim-update' && git push")
```

Provided I am in the temp directory gist repo was cloned to.

For the sake of the SE rules, here is the full script:

```
" Author: Maxim Kim <habamax@gmail.com>
" Desc: Sync current buffer with the github gist having the same file name.
"
" Prereqs:
" 1. Install and setup https://cli.github.com/
" 2. Put this file to ~/.vim/autoload/gist.vim
"
" Usage: Open file and :call gist#sync()
"
" Create helper command if needed
" command! GistSync call gist#sync()


func! gist#sync() abort
    if empty(bufname())
        echohl Error
        echomsg "Can't sync empty buffer!"
        echohl None
        return
    elseif empty(get(b:, 'gist_repo', '')) && !s:gist_init()
        echohl Error
        echomsg "Can't sync '" .. expand("%:t") .. "' gist!"
        echohl None
        return
    endif

    try
        exe printf('%write! %s/%s', b:gist_repo, expand('%:t'))
        let cwd = getcwd()
        exe 'lcd ' .. b:gist_repo
        call system("git add -A && git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m 'vim-update' && git push")
        if v:shell_error
            echohl Error
            echomsg "Can't sync '" .. expand("%:t") .. "' gist. Error code: " .. v:shell_error
            echohl None
            return
        else
            echomsg "Gist '" .. expand("%:t") .. "' is updated."
        endif
    finally
        exe 'lcd ' .. cwd
    endtry
endfunc


func! s:gist_init() abort
    let gist_id = s:gist_get_id()
    if empty(gist_id)
        echomsg "Gist '" .. expand("%:t") .. "' doesn't exist, creating..."
        try
            let cwd = getcwd()
            lcd %:p:h
            call system('gh gist create -p ' .. shellescape(expand("%:t")))
        finally
            exe 'lcd ' .. cwd
        endtry
        if v:shell_error
            echohl Error
            echomsg "Can't create '" .. expand("%:t") .. "' as a gist... Error code: " .. v:shell_error
            echohl None
            return v:false
        else
            let gist_id = s:gist_get_id()
        endif
        if exists("b:gist_repo")
            unlet b:gist_repo
        endif
    endif

    if !empty(gist_id) && empty(get(b:, 'gist_repo', ''))
        return s:gist_clone(gist_id)
    endif

    return v:true
endfunc


func! s:gist_clone(id) abort
    let gist_repo = tempname()
    call system(printf('gh gist clone %s %s', a:id, gist_repo))
    if v:shell_error
        echohl Error
        echomsg "Can't edit '" .. expand("%:t") .. "' as a gist... Error code: " .. v:shell_error
        echohl None
        return v:false
    else
        let b:gist_repo = gist_repo
        return v:true
    endif
endfunc


func! s:gist_info(gist) abort
    let gist = a:gist->split('\t')
    return [gist[0], gist[1]]
endfunc


func! s:gist_get_id() abort
    let gists = systemlist('gh gist list')->map({idx, val -> s:gist_info(val)})
    let idx = gists->copy()->map({idx, val -> val[1]})->index(expand('%:t'))
    if idx >= 0
        return gists[idx][0]
    else
        return ''
    endif
endfunc
```

Comment: This script looks great, thanks! I totally missed `gh gist clone`, which alone solves my problem, but your plugin is more useful (and educational to learn how to create a wrapper with Vimscript). Didn't accept it as answer (yet) because this doesn't answer the main question, but if there are no other `gh`-agnostic takes in a day or two then I will just change the question, and accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @toraritte did you ever follow up and see if this answered your question?

Comment: Apologies, forgot to follow up on this... Thanks for the reminder!